# Sort WooCommerce Products on shop page by Title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not able to sort the families by "Title" - Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is there something I need to add to the Custom Query that I'm not aware of?

```
        <h1 class="heading-14 _15mar center">Sponsored Families</h1>
       <?php 
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product' ,
                'posts_per_page'=> 10 ,
                'meta_query' => array( 
                    array( 
                    'key' => '_stock_status',
                    'orderby' = 'title',
                    'value' => 'instock',
                    'compare' => '!=' ) ), 'paged' => $paged );


            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {  
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                global $product; ?>
                <!--img src="" width="100%;"-->
                  <div class="div-block-60 fm-block">
                   <div class="div-block-61">
                    <div class="div-block-62">
                      <div class="family-image familypic family1" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>)">
                        <!--img src="" width="100%;"-->
                      </div>
                      <div class="buckettext">
```

Comment: You want to sort by the post_title?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to sort by the Post Title, you need to add the `orderby` parameter to your  `$args`.

```
'orderby' => 'post_title'
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters